# can I put open cv image (numpy array) into the central widget of main window using PyQt5?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I'm having trouble adding open_cv image(numpy array) to the central widget of my PyQt5 program.
As you can see the below image,  what I try to do is manipulate open cv window in the frame of Pyqt5 main window. I try to find a solution, but I can't find it. I'm pretty sure there is fine solution of it.
I hope many experts will help my problems.
thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):

        self.statusBar() 
        self.createActions() 
        self.createMenus() 
        self.image_frame = QLabel()

        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.resize(500, 350)
        # self.setGeometry(400, 300, 800, 400)
        self.center()
        self.show()
    
    
    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QAction("&Open...", self, shortcut = "Ctrl+O", triggered=self.open)
        self.exitAct = QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
    
    def createMenus(self):
    
        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct) 


        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)


    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry() 
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center() 
        qr.moveCenter(cp) 
        self.move(qr.topLeft()) 
    
    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', '',
                                                  'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', options=options)

        if fileName:
            self.sid = QImage(fileName)
            self.src_raw = self.qimg2cv(self.sid)  
            
            self.src = self.src_raw.copy()
            self.img = self.src.copy() 
            # print(self.img)
            self.show_image(self.img)
    
    def qimg2cv(self, q_img):
        q_img.save('temp.png', 'png')
        mat = cv2.imread('temp.png')
        return mat

    def show_image(self, A):
    
        cv2.namedWindow("image_window")
        cv2.moveWindow("image_window", 300,50)
        cv2.imshow("image_window", A)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sets the `self.image_frame` to be the main window's central widget.
2. Convert `self.img` to `pixmap`
3. Setting the pixmap

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, \
    QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QImage
import cv2
#? from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
#?        self.statusBar() 
        self.createActions() 
        self.createMenus() 
        
        self.image_frame = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.image_frame)                            # ! 1

        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.resize(500, 350)
        self.center()
        self.show()
    
    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QAction("&Open...", self, shortcut = "Ctrl+O", triggered=self.open)
        self.exitAct = QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
    
    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct) 
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry() 
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center() 
        qr.moveCenter(cp) 
        self.move(qr.topLeft()) 
    
    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', 
            '',
            'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', 
            options=options
        )

        if fileName:
            self.sid = QImage(fileName)
            self.src_raw = self.qimg2cv(self.sid)           
            self.src = self.src_raw.copy()
            self.img = self.src.copy() 
            self.show_image(self.img)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            # ! 2            
            height, width, bytesPerComponent = self.img.shape
            bytesPerLine = 3 * width
            cv2.cvtColor(self.img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, self.img)
            QImg = QImage(
                self.img.data, 
                width, 
                height, 
                bytesPerLine, 
                QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
            
            self.image_frame.setPixmap(pixmap)                              # ! 3           
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    
    def qimg2cv(self, q_img):                           
        q_img.save('temp_.png', 'png')
        mat = cv2.imread('temp_.png')                 
        return mat

    def show_image(self, A):
        cv2.namedWindow("image_window")
        cv2.moveWindow("image_window", 300,50)
        cv2.imshow("image_window", A)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your solution and detail explanation :)